# C# <exception > tag not showing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exception

My constructor throws an exception. So I tried to add this line above it:

```
/// <exception cref="System.Exception">Thrown when...</exception>
public Person(int serial)
{
    if(....)
        throw new System.Exception();
}
```

When I write in Main: `Person x = new Person(...` it doesn't show what exception this might throw (in the tooltip box). The same problem occurs also with indexer and in properties, if I want to show it only for Set.

If I write it above regular other methods, it does show it.

Thanks in advance.
Liron.

Comment: Working with ReSharper?

Comment: It does shows after constructing the instance and mouse hovered over the constructor. btw am using resharper if it matters

Comment: no ReSharper. Vs 2012. For constructor it shows only when mouse hover it, but this is not usefull cause I like to know about exceptions when creating the object while writing the code.

Comment: and for indexer it doesn't show at all

Comment: I don't really fully understand why it is important to know the Exceptions it is throwing. Usually, I never ever catch exceptions locally. [Also see Eric Lippert's posting](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/06/living-with-unchecked-exceptions-part-two/).

Answer (score 1):

If you do not include the information in the XML comments for a method, property, or field, and in the correct format, Visual studio will not pick it up and display it.
For a Constructor, the syntax would be:

```
/// <summary>
/// Create a person from a serial number
/// </summary>
/// <exception cref="ArgumentException">Thrown when serial number is outside valid     range</exception>
/// <param name="serial"></param>
public Person(int serial)
{
if (serial == 0)
    {
    throw new ArgumentException("Serial number cannot be zero");
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, even with this, exception information isn't displayed in Intellisense for constructors only in the generated documentation files!

[edit]Minor clarification[/edit]